# honeyd: ip-open: operation not permitted

Tags: interface, config, honeypot

I want to Use honeyd to setup a virtual host with the following specification:

• Operating System: Linux

• Ethernet MAC Address: 00:00:24:22:8c:14

• IP Address: 10.10.10.2

• Open Ports: 22

so I instlled honeyd on ubuntu 1204 vm; then changed etc/honeypot/honeyd.conf as below:

```
create default
set default default tcp action block
set default default udp action block
set default default icmp action block

create linux
set linux personality "Linux 2.4.20"
set linux default tcp action reset
add linux tcp port 22 open
set linux ethernet "00:00:24:22:8c:14"
bind 10.10.10.2 linux
```

and the file honeyd.conf in etc/default/ like below:

```
RUN="yes"
INTERFACE= "eth0"
NETWORK= 10.10.10.2
OPTIONS="--disable-webserver"
```

when i run the honeyd using command : 'honeyd start'
sometimes it shows this error:

```
honeyd: ip-open: operation not permitted
```

and other times it shows this one:

```
honeyd: interface_expandips: Invalid network range: start
```

what should i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run honeyd **without** `sudo` you will receive the first error message. The second one occurs when running it **with** `sudo`.

Looks like you didn't specify a network range in the config file at `/etc/default`. `10.10.10.2` is an IP address. Not a range. You probably want something like:

```
NETWORK= 10.10.10.0/24
```

in your config file,

Answer (score 0):

my error removed after i changed my vmware nat dhcp setting. it is in tab edit>virtual network editor.. > nat> dhcp setting.
the range must include the ip address i want to use.
:)